# How can I know the storage space provided by WINDOWS OS for Isolated Storage?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, isolatedstorage

How can I know the storage space provided for Isolated Storage by **Windows OS** ?

Can i know this by any method | property | class in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the available space for your isolated storage like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

public class CheckingSpace
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Get an isolated store for this assembly and put it into an
        // IsolatedStoreFile object.
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore =  IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User |
            IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);

        // Create a few placeholder files in the isolated store.
        new IsolatedStorageFileStream("InTheRoot.txt", FileMode.Create, isoStore);
        new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Another.txt", FileMode.Create, isoStore);
        new IsolatedStorageFileStream("AThird.txt", FileMode.Create, isoStore);
        new IsolatedStorageFileStream("AFourth.txt", FileMode.Create, isoStore);
        new IsolatedStorageFileStream("AFifth.txt", FileMode.Create, isoStore);

        Console.WriteLine(isoStore.AvailableFreeSpace + " bytes of space remain in this isolated store.");
    } // End of Main.
}
```

Comment: looks like AvailableFreeSpace property is .nEt FrameWork 4.0 feature cuz its not showing up in my console which is based on .net 3.5..

Comment: In previous versions use:
      long spaceLeft =(long)(isoStore.MaximumSize - isoStore.CurrentSize);

Comment: Hey,Thaxx  Brian Knight
Its giving a very big figure..Does Isolated Storage really has such a big space for an application....

Comment: Yep - there's a quota that can be set on the machine -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbe2d5h0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IsoltaedStorage has a property `AvailableFreeSpace`

[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.availablefreespace.aspx)

Comment: @downvoter: why this downvote ? accepted code says exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

There's two answers talking about how much space. Alternatively, you might be asking about [the location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which varies based on the OS:

> The following table shows the root locations where isolated storage is created on a few common operating systems. Look for Microsoft\IsolatedStorage directories under this root location

If it's neither of these (space available, location), then you need to edit your question and make it clearer what information you're looking for.

Comment: Hey,actually i want to know the total space provided for a particular application running on Windows Xp...